# Trying to load view controller with .nib fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, xib, nib

I have created a view controller via new file, I checked the create nib option and that went okay. I made a nice IB layout and things are great. The file owner is linked to the right ViewController, the view in the nib is linked to the view outlet in the file owner.

Now, I try to instantiate this view controller with the nib in AppDelegate.

```
TerminationViewController *terminatedVC = [[TerminationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TerminationViewController" bundle:nil];
terminatedVC.view.hidden = NO;
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:terminatedVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

There are no errors and I see a black screen. What am I doing wrong? I also checked the target membership for the nib.

**Edit**

```
self.window = [[[InterceptorWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

TerminationViewController *terminatedVC = [[TerminationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TerminationViewController" bundle:nil];
terminatedVC.view.hidden = NO;
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:terminatedVC animated:YES completion:nil];

// Wait for 10 seconds
double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    // Do something, next view controller.
}
```

Comment: can you post whole code that is called in applicationDidFinishLaunching?

Comment: I have done so :)

Comment: i don't see anywhere [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: It happens in the block in dispatch_after, so should I do that before?

Comment: I would not recommend to call this in delayed block

Comment: Solved it, thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome, just please accept my answer ;-)

Comment: Of course ;) Done that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; in applicationDidFinishLaunching